# Get contact number from contact list in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

When the user clicks a button in my app, I want to open the contact list for the user to select a contact.  I then want to get the phone number for the selected contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [BlackBerryContactList.choose()](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Select_contact_from_contact_list_565501_11.jsp).

```
BlackBerryContactList list = (BlackBerryContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
        PIMItem contact = list.choose();
        if(contact != null){
            String mobileNumber="";
            for(int i=0; i < contact.countValues(Contact.TEL); i++)
            {
                if(contact.getAttributes(Contact.TEL, i) == Contact.ATTR_MOBILE)
                    mobileNumber = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i);  
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thankq vivart.but i need to get mobile number from selected contact

Comment: vivart.i need to get phone number from selected contact from contact list i execute this code.when i select mobile number it is directly making call.for my app i need to send sms to selected contact programetically

Comment: the code is not working. when i click a contact, its didnt displaying anything.