# Blackberry, searching contacts from list

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to add an Search Box in list Field. so that  When i Enter a letter, then it will show the names starting with the letter 'A' , and so on. Iam using Vector to save the list of contacts same as the image shown : [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select from the Contacts, use the `ContactList.choose()` method.

DO NOT try to iterate through the entire contacts your self every time. Remember there are lot of people having thousands of contacts and your code will be very unresponsive.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4436816/371534

However, if you want to have '*filter as you type*' kind of functionality with some other data, use the `KeywordFilterField`. You can get a sample code for it in the BlackBerry JDK samples.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `FieldChangeListener` (or listen for alphanumeric key presses) to your EditField. Then refresh the list each time. Filtering on entries starting with the string contained in the EditField.

I wrote this on a pc without the Blackberry plugin installed, so couldn't test it, but it should be something like this.

```
String prefix = editField.getText();
Enumeration e = list.items();
while(e.hasMoreElements())
{
    PIMItem item = (PIMItem) e.nextElement();
    String name = item.getString(PIMItem.NAME,0);
    if (name.startsWith(prefix))
    {
        //TODO display on screen
    }
}
```